# List all organizations form Github using Octokit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, octokit

In my rails app I would like to list user's organziations and their repositories. I am authenticating with Github using omniauth-github so once I obtain the token from Github I do this:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => token)
client.orgs
```

In omniauth.rb

`provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET']`

It throws an error
`GET https://api.github.com/user/orgs: 403 - You need at least read:org scope or user scope to list your organizations. // See: https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-your-organizations`

So I add that to the initializer and restart the server:

`provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'], scope: 'read:org'`

but I get the same error.

I tried providing the scope in Octokit client as well:

`client.create_authorization({:idempotent => true, :client_id => 'xxxx', :client_secret => 'yyyy', :scopes => ["read:org"]})`

but I get a message that only basic authentication is allowed here.

I would like to ask you, what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the proper read rights on the OAuth token used by your app? (https://github.com/settings/developers)

Comment: I have set everything to Read Only so I should have access to it but I am getting 403 error message. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have logged in without giving permission for the scope 'read:org'. You might want to try to re-login and see if you need to give your permission for the newly added scope. It could well be that there's a mismatch between your database in Rails/tokens and the GitHub OAuth flow.

Comment: I have tried logging out, authenticating again in my app but I get the same error. I do not store tokens in my database as I don't think they are sessions persistent.

Answer (score 0):

After deeper investigation I've figured out that fetching organizations requires basic authentication (username and password) or [OAuth token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) so I created a token and it works fine now.